ReactDOMServer's renderToString method throwing error : clearProviders is not a function
We are using server side rendering with GraalVM. Application is throwing below error
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: <this>.clearProviders is not a function
        at <js>.b.destroy(propertysrp.js:1566)
        at <js>.renderToString(propertysrp.js:1566)

I have checked in React source repository on github, and i have found that  in ReactPartialRenderer.js file the function clearProviders is defined on line number 821, we are using webpack to bundle the JS, function calling of clearProviders is coming from destroy() method from line number 757, both are mentioned in the same file then why the definition of clearProviders is missing in bundled JS
here is bundled file snippet where clearProviders function calling is mentioned , but actual definition is missing in whole file, in what scenario this thing happens, it was working fine , we did not made any changes to react versioning, we just rebuild the application after some minor changes and error appeared
,t.version="16.14.0"},function(e,t,r){
/** @license React v16.14.0
 * react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
var n=r(110),o=r(0);function i(e){for(var t="https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant="+e,r=1;r<arguments.length;r++)t+="&args[]="+encodeURIComponent(arguments[r]);return"Minified React error #"+e+"; visit "+t+" for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings."}var a=((r="function"==typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for)&&Symbol.for("react.portal"),r?Symbol.for("react.fragment"):60107);r&&Symbol.for("react.strict_mode"),r&&Symbol.for("react.profiler"),r&&Symbol.for("react.provider"),r&&Symbol.for("react.context"),r&&Symbol.for("react.concurrent_mode"),r&&Symbol.for("react.forward_ref"),r&&Symbol.for("react.suspense"),r&&Symbol.for("react.suspense_list"),r&&Symbol.for("react.memo"),r&&Symbol.for("react.lazy"),r&&Symbol.for("react.block"),r&&Symbol.for("react.fundamental"),r&&Symbol.for("react.scope");for(var c=((r=o.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED).hasOwnProperty("ReactCurrentDispatcher")||(r.ReactCurrentDispatcher={current:null}),r.hasOwnProperty("ReactCurrentBatchConfig")||(r.ReactCurrentBatchConfig={suspense:null}),{}),l=new Uint16Array(16),u=0;u<15;u++)l[u]=u+1;l[15]=0,Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,"children dangerouslySetInnerHTML defaultValue defaultChecked innerHTML suppressContentEditableWarning suppressHydrationWarning style".split(" ").forEach((function(e){})),[["acceptCharset","accept-charset"],["className","class"],["htmlFor","for"],["httpEquiv","http-equiv"]].forEach((function(e){e[0]})),["contentEditable","draggable","spellCheck","value"].forEach((function(e){e.toLowerCase()})),["autoReverse","externalResourcesRequired","focusable","preserveAlpha"].forEach((function(e){})),"allowFullScreen async autoFocus autoPlay controls default defer disabled disablePictureInPicture formNoValidate hidden loop noModule noValidate open playsInline readOnly required reversed scoped seamless itemScope".split(" ").forEach((function(e){e.toLowerCase()})),["checked","multiple","muted","selected"].forEach((function(e){})),["capture","download"].forEach((function(e){})),["cols","rows","size","span"].forEach((function(e){})),["rowSpan","start"].forEach((function(e){e.toLowerCase()}));var s=/[\-:]([a-z])/g;function f(e){return e[1].toUpperCase()}"accent-height alignment-baseline arabic-form baseline-shift cap-height clip-path clip-rule color-interpolation color-interpolation-filters color-profile color-rendering dominant-baseline enable-background fill-opacity fill-rule flood-color flood-opacity font-family font-size font-size-adjust font-stretch font-style font-variant font-weight glyph-name glyph-orientation-horizontal glyph-orientation-vertical horiz-adv-x horiz-origin-x image-rendering letter-spacing lighting-color marker-end marker-mid marker-start overline-position overline-thickness paint-order panose-1 pointer-events rendering-intent shape-rendering stop-color stop-opacity strikethrough-position strikethrough-thickness stroke-dasharray stroke-dashoffset stroke-linecap stroke-linejoin stroke-miterlimit stroke-opacity stroke-width text-anchor text-decoration text-rendering underline-position underline-thickness unicode-bidi unicode-range units-per-em v-alphabetic v-hanging v-ideographic v-mathematical vector-effect vert-adv-y vert-origin-x vert-origin-y word-spacing writing-mode xmlns:xlink x-height".split(" ").forEach((function(e){e.replace(s,f)})),"xlink:actuate xlink:arcrole xlink:role xlink:show xlink:title xlink:type".split(" ").forEach((function(e){e.replace(s,f)})),["xml:base","xml:lang","xml:space"].forEach((function(e){e.replace(s,f)})),["tabIndex","crossOrigin"].forEach((function(e){e.toLowerCase()})),["src","href","action","formAction"].forEach((function(e){e.toLowerCase()})),Object.is;var p=(n({menuitem:!0},m={area:!0,base:!0,br:!0,col:!0,embed:!0,hr:!0,img:!0,input:!0,keygen:!0,link:!0,meta:!0,param:!0,source:!0,track:!0,wbr:!0}),{animationIterationCount:!0,borderImageOutset:!0,borderImageSlice:!0,borderImageWidth:!0,boxFlex:!0,boxFlexGroup:!0,boxOrdinalGroup:!0,columnCount:!0,columns:!0,flex:!0,flexGrow:!0,flexPositive:!0,flexShrink:!0,flexNegative:!0,flexOrder:!0,gridArea:!0,gridRow:!0,gridRowEnd:!0,gridRowSpan:!0,gridRowStart:!0,gridColumn:!0,gridColumnEnd:!0,gridColumnSpan:!0,gridColumnStart:!0,fontWeight:!0,lineClamp:!0,lineHeight:!0,opacity:!0,order:!0,orphans:!0,tabSize:!0,widows:!0,zIndex:!0,zoom:!0,fillOpacity:!0,floodOpacity:!0,stopOpacity:!0,strokeDasharray:!0,strokeDashoffset:!0,strokeMiterlimit:!0,strokeOpacity:!0,strokeWidth:!0}),d=["Webkit","ms","Moz","O"],y=(Object.keys(p).forEach((function(e){d.forEach((function(t){t=t+e.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+e.substring(1),p[t]=p[e]}))})),o.Children.toArray);r.ReactCurrentDispatcher,Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,g.prototype.destroy=function(){var e;this.exhausted||(this.exhausted=!0,this.clearProviders(),e=this.threadID,l[e]=l[0],l[0]=e)};var h=g,m={renderToString:function(e){e=new h(e,!1);try{return e.read(1/0)}finally{e.destroy()}},renderToStaticMarkup:function(e){e=new h(e,!0);try{return e.read(1/0)}finally{e.destroy()}},renderToNodeStream:function(){throw Error(i(207))},renderToStaticNodeStream:function(){throw Error(i(208))},version:"16.14.0"};function g(e,t){if(e={type:null,domNamespace:"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",children:e=o.isValidElement(e)&&(e.type!==a||(e=e.props.children,o.isValidElement(e)))?[e]:y(e),childIndex:0,context:c,footer:""},0===(r=l[0])){var r,n=l,u=2*(r=n.length);if(!(u<=65536))throw Error(i(304));var s=new Uint16Array(u);for(s.set(n),(l=s)[0]=r+1,n=r;n<u-1;n++)l[n]=n+1;l[u-1]=0}else l[0]=l[r];this.threadID=r,this.stack=[e],this.exhausted=!1,this.currentSelectValue=null,this.previousWasTextNode=!1,this.makeStaticMarkup=t,this.suspenseDepth=0,this.contextIndex=-1,this.contextStack=[],this.contextValueStack=[]}e.exports=m.default||m},function(e,t,r){

here is the webpack configuration
function serverComponentEntry (componentName) {
  return {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: `./react-src/${componentName}/${componentName}-server.js`,

    
    output: {
      filename: `${componentName}.js`,
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, OUTPUT_PATH + '/' + TARGET_SERVER)
     
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin([TARGET_SERVER], {
        root: BASE_PATH + '/' + OUTPUT_PATH
      }),
      new UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('release')
        }
      }),
      new DotenvCmdWebpack({filePath: ENV_FILE_PATH, env: "constant"})
      
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          loader: 'null-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff2?)$/,
          loader: 'null-loader'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            <StaticRouter> 
          <Provider store={store1}>
            <App/>
          </Provider>
        </StaticRouter> 
    );

in our package.json these are the version we are using for react and react-dom
"react-dom": "16.14.0",
"react": "16.14.0",


Ok, so problem was with UglifyJsPlugin, replacing it with terser webpack plugin
solved it, i am not sure what was the root cause, why uglifyJsPlugin was working fine till now and suddenly throwing this error, we were using latest version  "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0"
